# Uncaught TypeError: The "original" argument must be of type Function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

when I start the react application, using `npm start` , I am encountering this error ,
there are lot of questions around this error, but I am unable to understand the root cause of this error. Please Explain.

```
Uncaught TypeError: The "original" argument must be of type Function
        at Object.promisify (util.js:601:1)
        at ./node_modules/env-cmd/dist/parse-rc-file.js (parse-rc-file.js:7:1)
        at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:789:1)
        at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
        at ./node_modules/env-cmd/dist/get-env-vars.js (get-env-vars.js:3:1)
        at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:789:1)
        at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
        at ./node_modules/env-cmd/dist/index.js (index.js:6:1)
        at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:789:1)
        at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
        at ./src/components/layout_components/exec_layout/choicePageLayout.js (view-all-customers.svg:1:1)
        at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:789:1)
        at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
        at ./src/components/layout_components/exec_layout/indexPageLayout.js (demoLayout.js:424:1)
        at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:789:1)
        at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
        at ./src/components/layout_components/login/login.js (login.css?7228:45:1)
        at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:789:1)
        at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
        at ./src/index.js (index.css?ac04:45:1)
        at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:789:1)
        at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
        at 1 (helper.js:12:1)
        at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:789:1)
        at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45:1)
        at Array.webpackJsonpC
```

Comment: Please provide your code

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It would be really helpful if you provide the code that is causing this error...

My guess, after looking at the error would be, that you are calling some function somewhere in a parameter of another function at `parse-rc-file.js:7:1` instead of passing the function directly.

*eg:* `someFnExpectingACallback(myFunction())` instead of `someFnExpectingACallback(myFunction)`

Take a look at [callback functions](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_callback.asp)